# What unit does the File API use for .size

Tags: html, file, api, file-upload

I have been wondering for a while now but I don't know how I should test this. If I allow users to upload a file (or rather "select a file from their system) and I want the file to not be larger than X size, I'd do it like so:

```
    var file = $("#xml-upload-button")[0].files[0],
        fsize = file.size;

    if (fsize < 20000) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            if (reader.result) {
                // Something
            }
            else {
                // Something
            }
        };
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

This works, that's not the problem. I am simply wondering what unit the File API uses for my `fsize` value. Bits, or bytes? The difference is crucial. Would I say to users that they can upload a file that's max 2.5kB, or rather 20kB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer, [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Getting_information_about_selected_file(s)) stated:

> **size**
>
> The size of the file in bytes as a read-only 64-bit integer.